# Tree view visible in win XP but not in Windows 7

Tags: .net, asp.net, treeview

i have a problem in .net web application...
i have created a tree view which runs perfect on windows XP but as i try to run this application on windows7 the tree view is not displayed/visible .
i could not able to find the solution so please give me the solution...

thanks in advance....

Comment: 12 questions and no accepted answers!  You should go back and click the "tick" mark next to the best answer for some of your questions - else less people will answer them in future...

Answer (score 1):

If it's a web application and "runs perfect" on XP, my assumption would be that you mean it works when you *view it* from a browser in XP - I'd assume that you're hosting it on a different machine.  That being the case, there are a huge potential list of concerns...

- you could be using a custom web control (say, an ActiveX control) that works in earlier IE but doesn't run under IE8's stricter security
- you could have a markup/standards compatibility problem
- you could have something installed on the XP machine (an IE plugin) that's not on the win7 machine (or doesn't work under IE8)

It's important to identify what the real culprit is.  I would guess that it's the differing browsers, not the differing OS - is your WinXP machine running IE7 (or even 6)?  Does it still work in XP if you upgrade to IE8?  Does it work in a non-IE browser (Firefox, Opera, Chrome) on either OS?

Ultimately there's not enough to go on in your question to solve the problem, but there are plenty of avenues to investigate.